# day and time in Java

Tags: java

How can I get current time and day in Java?
I'd like to name files based on day and time.

For example if:

```
Day : march 25th, 1993
Hour : 12.20 pm
```

then the file name should be: `250319931220`

Is this something I as a beginner can achieve?

Thank you

Comment: Don't you prefer 199303251220?  Your files would sort better this way…

Answer (score 4):

To get the current date, use [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
Date now = new Date();
```

To format it in a human friendly string representation, use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String name = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm").format(now);
```

*Click the above `SimpleDateFormat` link to see all available format patterns*.

Alternatively, you can also just get the current timestamp by [`System#currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Customizing date and time formats](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmm");
    String result = df.format(now.getTime());
```

Lots of methods on java.util.Date are deprecated, it is generally preferred to access the current time through the Calendar class.

Check the [javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to refine the output to get the exact String you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Date` class. random google example here: http://www.java-examples.com/simple-java-date-example

Answer (score 0):

Another option, besides `Date`, would be to use `Calendar`, which seems to be the non-deprecated replacement for `Date`.  It can let you query a whole bunch about different pieces of information, from which you should be able to construct your string.

Out of curiosity, are you sure that you want to store files with this structure?  It seems that using some other format (perhaps the number of seconds since the start of the UNIX epoch) might be easier to parse.

EDIT: To clarify, `Date` itself isn't deprecated; rather most of the methods you'd use to extract formatted data from it is.  Thanks to commenters for pointing this out!

Comment: Your idea sounds interesting. Is what you're suggesting easier to do?

Comment: Calendar is by no means a replacement for Date, and Date is not deprecated. What happened is that after the release of Java 1.0, people realized that the date arithmetic API present in Date was woefully inadequate. Calendar was introduced to fix that, and Date remains as a thin semantic wrapper around a long timestamp, which is just the right thing for representing a timestamp in a data model (where a Calendar instance would be very memory inefficient due to its large number of arithmetic-related fields).

Comment: Almost certainly.  You can get this time by calling `new Date().getTime()` to get the number of milliseconds since the start of the Unix epoch as a `long`.  You can also rebuild a `Date` object from this time by using `new Date(numberOfMillis)`, which could be useful in your application.

Comment: The `Date` class isn't deprecated. Only most of its methods are. The `Calendar` isn't much better by the way. The ultimate solution would be using JodaTime, but that's not necessary for this particular simple requirement. Note that `new Date().getTime()` has an unnecessary overhead of a new `Date` instance. Just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; 
Would this equivalent to what you suggested? thank you

Comment: @tewr- Sure, that should work.  I think the number of millis is probably a better measure though, since there's no reason to sacrifice precision unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. This should do what you're looking for:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's Calendar class to get this information. More information on Calendar is available here

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

To do what you want - you'd do something like this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); // Gives you the current time
String fileName = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + now.get(Calendar.YEAR) + now.get(Calendar.HOUR) + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you agree it's best to put the year first, in year-month-date order for chronological sorting alphabetically. If not, twiddle with the format codes for your way.

Using the third-party library [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 rather than the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

If you are mixing these files from different computers that may be in a different time zone, or a computer that is moving between time zones, it may be best to record the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT date-time (no time zone offset, 'Z' on end signifies [Zulu time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Vancouver" ) );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
System.out.println( "now in local terms: " + formatter.print( now ) );

DateTimeFormatter formatterUtcIso = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute().withZoneUTC();
//DateTimeFormatter formatterUtcIso = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis().withZoneUTC();
System.out.println( "now in UTC for ISO: " + formatterUtcIso.print( now ) );

DateTimeFormatter formatterUtcIsoSpaced = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss'Z'").withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "now in UTC for ISO with a space: " + formatterUtcIsoSpaced.print( now ) );
```

When run…

```
now in local terms: 20131223203714
now in UTC for ISO: 2013-12-24T04:37
now in UTC for ISO with a space: 2013-12-24 04-37-14Z
```